# I have 2 vectors of data. How can I plot data from one vector for some specific values from the other vector?

Tags: matlab

For example, if I have the 2 vectors in Matlab:

```
WindSpeed = 1:10; 
PlumeDepth = 6:15;
```

I want to plot (or to make a histogram) the whole `PlumeDepth` vector for `WindSpeed = 5`, `WindSpeed = 6`, and `WindSpeed = 8` separately. Does anyone have any idea? I tried some for and if loops, but it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
WindSpeed = [12.3025 11.2528 12.5205 12.1426 11.8742 12.3042 11.5884 11.8757 10.9501 12.2123]
vector = [9,10]     % 10 for 12.2123 and 9 for 10.9501
for ii = vector
    plot(WindSpeed(ii),OlumeDepth);hold on
end
```

Comment: It won't work. I already tried this. I mean, I have a vector PlumeDepth and a vector WindSpeed which contains values from 9 m/s to 20 m/s roughly. I want to plot PlumeDepth at different wind speeds, namely at 10 m/s and 12 m/s. So PlumeDepth should change at each wind speed value. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: You may update your post with a real example. The way you are explaining it, I cannot understand. Give some example, that is producing the error.

Comment: Alright. I have the 2 vectors: `WindSpeed = [12.3025823763851 11.2528576671174 12.5205993776982 12.1426419902909 11.8742015052075 12.3042241887587 11.5884070863355 11.8757000823391 10.9501130120090 12.2123835207634]` and `PlumeDepth = [160 178 155 167 153 154 158 155 177 164]`. I want to plot `PlumeDepth` at `WindSpeed = 10.9501130120090` and `WindSpeed = 12.2123835207634`.

Comment: check my update, let me know if it is what you want.